# Andengine GLES2 - background thread blocks TimerUpdate

Tags: java, android, multithreading, andengine

I have fadeOut metod to well fadeOut scene, load another in background and fadeIn it. For fadeOut current scene I use black rectangle and TimerHandler for fade effect. To load second scene I use another thread.

My code:

```
public void fadeOut(final BasicScene scene){

    final Thread backgroundLoad = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!scene.isLoaded()) {
                scene.load();
            }
            threadSync("load",scene);
        }
    });

    TimerHandler backgroudLoadingDelay = new TimerHandler(0.1f,false,new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

        }
    });

    blackRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    blackRectangle.setAnchorCenter(0, 0);
    blackRectangle.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0f);
    mEngine.getScene().attachChild(blackRectangle);
    PauseableTimerHandler fadeoutHandler = new PauseableTimerHandler(0.01f, new PauseableTimerHandler.ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTick(PauseableTimerHandler pTimerHandle) {
            blackRectangle.setAlpha(blackRectangle.getAlpha() + 0.025f);
            if (blackRectangle.getAlpha() >= 1){
                blackRectangle.setAlpha(1f);
                mEngine.getScene().unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandle);
                threadSync("transition",scene);
            }
        }
    });
    mEngine.getScene().registerUpdateHandler(fadeoutHandler);
    backgroundLoad.start();
}

private void threadSync(String thread, BasicScene scene) {
    if (thread.equals("load")){
        loadingDone = true;
    } else if (thread.equals("transition")){
        transitionDone = true;
    }
    if(loadingDone && transitionDone){
        loadingDone = transitionDone = false;
        mEngine.setScene(scene.showScene());
        scene.fadeIn();
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                blackRectangle.detachSelf();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But on my both devices (SE wt19i and desire 500) I got sharp in fade effect. They aren't when I don't load anything so I guess it's because I start another thread? Am I right or there is another way?

Comment: Why not use the built in modifiers?

Comment: Now I discover them I will give them a chance... but tomorrow :)